# set $variable for Arguments Name ( NOT VALUE OF ARGUMENT) in graphql

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

i used Apollo in ReactNative Project

i want get some products from server with Query component in ApolloClient , my query schema is some thing like this

```
 products(isExisting:true) {
    id
    name
  }
```

this Query give me all available products and also i have this query too with different Argument

```
products(minPrice:$price)
   id
   name
 }
```

now i want create program for conditional for choose between 2 Arguments , in Plane [A] use (isExisting) arg and in Plane [B] use (minPrice)

my first and stupid solution is create 2 different query component , is it any other way , for example set Variable for arguments like this

```
 products($choose:$value)
```

also i know about directive in graphql https://graphql.github.io/learn/queries/#directives

but i think this is just for field

also my second solution for resolve this put javascript variable in `` , like this

```
   render() {

      const arg = 'minPrice';

          return(
               <Query
                  variables={{ }}
                    query={gql`

                           query {
                              products(${arg}:100) {
                                 id
                                 name }
```

i am checked this , working well for me , but i want know this is good and better way

Answer (score 1):

I think last solution , is good idea for doing this approach , also you must know directive just working for filed

```
 products(isExist:true) {
    name @include if(false/true)
 }
```

this means if conditions return True you get ( name ) field and if return False , ( name ) field not included in your query

also you can this directive

```
 products(isExist:true) {
    name @skip if(false/true)
 }


     @include(if: Boolean) Only include this field in the result if the            argument is true.
      @skip(if: Boolean) Skip this field if the argument is true.
```

Comment: thanks @parisa , but i think this is dirty way , must exist better way for solve this i think , but thanks for  give me good information about directive